# Why isn't anyone discussing Trump and Hilary?

Tags: discussion

I find this kind of odd. The last question about Trump was posted on Politics in December, and the one about Hillary predates it. Now why is that?

Answer (score 9):

One reason could be that politics.stackexchange.com is an international community with users from all around the world. When you read some questions you will notice that many of them are not US-centric. The US pre-election is not that relevant for large parts of the userbase.

Second, this is not a discussion forum, it's a website about factual question and answers. There are not many relevant questions you could ask about Mrs. Clinton and Donald which are fact-based (not opinion-based) and not answered with a quick internet search.

But when you have ideas for any such questions, feel free to ask. Politics.SE is behind its daily question quota for a public beta, so any constructive on-topic questions are welcome.

Comment: I can't think of any questions to ask about Trump or Clinton that aren't either a) already answered in the reams and reams every US news site already publishes about them every day, b) myth-debunking better suited to Skeptics ([example](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/31549/did-hillary-clinton-admit-in-her-memoirs-to-creating-isis)), c) broad, vague, open-ended or speculative, more suited to open-ended discussion than SE-style Q&A ([possible example](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/9743/why-is-donald-trump-so-popular), though I think that one is borderline-okay)

Answer (score 3):

As someone living in South America but very interested in politics, I'm finding more interesting right now the Taiwan Elections and the challenges of the '1992 Consensus' than a *fight* between a magnate (that *could* run for president) and a former First Lady/Secretary of State (which can also *could* run for president) which don't have anything but at minimum of something constructive.

Also, the *fight* between one possible candidate with another comes since 2013 and frankly, there's nothing interesting in that.

Comment: Good for you. Here's a +1 for your pains.